# Extending a Virtual Environment

Tags: python, virtualenv, python-venv, virtual-environment

The scenario is I have a main virtual environment and I want to implement a functionality where basically user is able to create a new virtual environment extending that main virtual environment (user's environment will be created while main environment is activated ) .

What I mean by extending a virtual environment is that the main environment's packages should be usable in user's environment i.e. there should be no copying and if a user installs a package that already exist in main environment with a different version then this version should get used in user's environment instead of main env's version .

I tried using virtualenv --system-site-packages option and though there were some positive result I landed up in some problem described below .

The main environment also has a base environment and whenever I use virtualenv --system-site-packages option , instead of main env's path , base env's path gets added to the sys.path of user's env .

I'll show 3 attributes of sys path that may help understanding the problem

```
Main Environment : sys path
sys.real_prefix : A this is base of main env path
sys.base_prefix : B
sys.prefix = B  : this is main env's path

User's Environment :
sys.real_prefix : invalid attribute
sys.base_prefix : A this is base of main env's path
sys.prefix = C  : this is user env's path
```

The user's env was created while keeping main env activated . Python Version : 3.5.3